# React use different value of input field than it is showing

Tags: html, reactjs

I am using number format internationalization for input field.
e.g.my input field will take input values as 12,555.8 but when I submit form, I want to use value 12555.8 without comma.

I am using library react-number-format which is taking care of both the formats. 
My question is how can I attach the 12555.8 number without comma to input field so that when I submit form, I can use that value?

```
<NumberFormat  
                    thousandSeparator={this.props.thousandSeparator}
                    decimalSeparator={this.props.decimalSeparator}
                    value={this.state.formattedValue}
                    valOriginal={this.modifiedInputValue}
                    onKeyUp={(event) => {this.onKeyUpFormatted(event)}}
                    onValueChange={(values) => {
                        const {formattedValue, floatValue} = values;
                        this.modifiedInputValue = isNaN(floatValue)?'':floatValue;
                        this.setState({formattedValue});
                    }}
                />
```

I tried this code and while form submit tried to capture non formatted value like following

```
event.target.elements.valOriginal
```

Comment: Could you show your code and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you been read the [docs](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format#examples)? I think it's so example are there.

Comment: Added code snippet which I tried

Comment: Shouldn't you do `setState(floatValue)`?

Comment: I want to show formatted value as value on input field but while using in code, I want plain number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added property as data-valOriginal for React element. After this, we can access this value as element.dataset.valOriginal during submit form event.

Answer (score -1):

> I am using library react-number-format which is taking care of both the formats. My question is how can I attach the 12555.8 number without comma to input field so that when I submit form, I can use that value?

You do NOT want to attach the value of 12555.8 without the comma to the input field. Whenever you modify the "value" of an input field, you will be changing what is displayed for the user.

Instead, the solution is to do all data-modification outside of the form, right before it is submitted.

So on your form, you'll want to have an "onSubmit" handler, and in your react component, you'll define:

```
onSubmitHandler = (formData) => {
  let cleanFormData = {...formData}
  cleanFormData.myNumberInput = cleaningFunction(cleanFormData.myNumberInput)
  //submit cleanFormData to server
}
```